# Search Box and Checkbox filter with Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to build filter system with Vue.

### Updated

Filters working, but all the functions computed are separeted functions. So How can I make those in one function and use it.

```js
export default {

    data() {
        return {
            estates: [],
            search: '',
            regions:['関西','関東','京橋'],
            checkedRegions:[]
        }
    },
    created(){
        axios.get('/ajax').then((response) => {
            this.estates = response.data;
        });
    },
    computed: {
        one: function() {
            var result =  this.estates.filter((estate) =>
                estate.building_name.match(this.search)
            );
            if(this.checkedRegions.length && this.checkedRooms.length) {
                return result.filter(estate => this.checkedRegions.includes(estate.region) && this.checkedRooms.includes(estate.rooms))
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <input type="text" v-model="search" name="" placeholder="search estate" value="">
                <div v-for="estate in filteredestate" class="card-body">
                    <h2>{{estate.building_name}}</h2>
                    <p>{{estate.address}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

`filteredestate` `filteredRegions` and `filteredRooms` make one function. for example how to return those function with `&&` ? And use it in this div.

```
<div v-for="estate in oneFunction" class="card-body">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your filter search result first as variable and you can check filter by `or(||)` expression !

> I modified `this` inside arrow function by setting to that variable and on the last line return `result` as default

```
one: function() {
  var that = this;
  var result =  this.estates.filter((estate) =>
    estate.building_name == that.search;
  );
  if(this.checkedRegions.length || this.checkedRooms.length) {
    return result.filter(estate => that.checkedRegions.includes(estate.region) || that.checkedRooms.includes(estate.rooms))
    }
  // when region and room length is 0
  return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, but when I run it error popping up for each function inside one; `Vue warn]: Property or method "filteredRegion" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.`

Comment: remove `filteredRegion` from your render ! As you request I merge three function to one ! So use `one` in your render for loop

Comment: the error is disappeared but, when I change the card-body's for loop to "one" I can't see the data... something is not right I guess.. if you need to see it then you can check the image here https://imgur.com/a/ZSbqm71

Comment: okay, improved your code and solved the problem. but it thanks to you, it's working now I am checking this as answer. also updating the question. you can check what I changed

Answer (score 0):

`rooms` and `regions` are arrays. So you need to iterate through these arrays in order to render the checkboxes.

instead of this:

```
<input type="checkbox" v-model="checkedLocations"  v-bind:value="regions">関東 <input/>
<input type="checkbox" v-model="checkedLocations"  v-bind:value="regions">関西 <input/>
<input type="checkbox" v-model="checkedLocations"  v-bind:value="regions">北海道<input/>
```

should be like this:

```
<template v-for="region in regions">
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="checkedLocations"  v-bind:value="region.id">region.region<input/>
</template>
```

similar should be done with `rooms`.

Also, in js part, you have `checkedRegions` while in template you have `checkedLocations`. I guess this should be too `checkedRegions`.